# Translating TLD to Query String Parameter via mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, internationalization

Looking for some help with a mod rewrite condition/rule combination which achieves the following:

If TLD is .fr and lang=fr is not a current parameter.

- If there are no current parameters add ?lang=fr to the request internally.
- If there are currently parameters add &lang=fr to the request internally.

At present I am detecting TLD correctly, but unable to add the "logic" to determine how to handle query string parameter amendments. I need to be able to do this to run through 5 or 6 possible TLDs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.([^\.]*?)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1
```

The first line parses the top level domain and *stores* it in %1.
The second line checks if any language is already set if not
is in (the third line) the language parameter added to the request url.